# push data from server to client with specified Id signalR

Tags: signalr

I received data from different server to my Hub class. Each data has its own ID. Whenever data comes to the server hub, it push my data to the client. This is like job progress.
I want to send each ID to the client with unique hub id., How do I filter the message from the server? I used in this way `Clients.Client("ID1").send(data);` Or I have to specify in caller property? Anyone can help me.

With Regards,
Shanthini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ConnectionId` to identify the client.

When new client is connected, store `ConnectionId` somewhere so that you can use it later to identify the client.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        // store connectionId somewhere
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

To send data to the client, identify it by  `ConnectionId`:

```
public void SendNewData(string connectionId, object data)
{
    var Context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    Context.Clients.Client(connectionId).send(data);
}
```

If you need to identify clients by some other ID, then you should store relationship between your ID and `ConnectionId`.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to save my connectionId in the database at the moment. Before that I have another question. All my data coming through the queue. When it hits the server hub, it push the data to the client. Now, how do I know which data is hitting my hub? Hub receives the data from the queue; Its a continuous process. Come, hit and display., Then how can I filter each data? Is that make sense?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Consider hub as a way to run a remote procedure with passing some data as parameters (client procedure from server or server procedure from client). All the other is related to your application logic (when to call the procedure, what should this procedure do with the data recieved, etc).

Comment: Oh thank you very much., I have done my requirement by using your answer :)

Comment: This fails form me when i"m trying to call my own connection id