# PUSH on event "DB Data Changes" using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, signalr

All right I followed the chat application demo just fine, a couple of other tuts as well, but all of them combined doesn't answer or due to my lack of intelligence to derive the answer I want. The scenario is as follows

I am building a website with

1. MVC 4
2. .NET Framework 4.0
3. IIS 7.5
4. ASP.NET 4
5. SQL Server 2008 R2

that is to accompany a desktop app, i.e. my web application and the desktop app will be interacting with the same DB. I want to add an AMS (Acess Management System) to the website and the desktop application, so that Users access rights to any function inside the apps can be managed finely grained. I want the changes to be PUSHED to the wesite in realtime.

For Example: A manager from the desktop app revokes the rights of the clerks to view sales reports, and a couple of clerks were online on the website, so I want those changes to be PUSHED to the website as they are made.

Now currently I am storing the rights of the users at login, so that with the increasing number of users wont cause the performance of the website to degrade quickly, now I know that when checking for every action either allowed or not, I can make a round trip to the DB and check for the condition, but as I said earlier, that would degrade the performance.

Now I want to PUSH the rights of the users to the website if there are some changes, either from the website itself or the desktop app, I looked into SignalR, and I found a solution here on SO ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188029/how-do-i-send-messages-from-server-to-client-using-signalr-hubs) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709859/push-data-from-server-to-client-with-specified-id-signalr)), but I don't want a clock ticker running continuously and then broadcasting the changes to all connected clients. And the user that is being changed, maybe connected to the website or maybe not. Please can someone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have spent much time on trying to find a solution for this, and the simplest I've found, using SignalR, is to use Hubs as a gateway to your Repository/API:

So, here's how the project would be set up:

1. ASP.NET MVC Controllers' Actions dish out entire pages.

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
           //
           // GET: /Home/
           public ActionResult Index()
           {
                 return View();
           }
   }
   ```
2. The View should be wrapped in a Layout that loads a Knockout MVVM. The View then initializes the part of the MVVMs that need to be used (as in, lump all your MVVM script in one file, and the View initializes the SignalR connections, to avoid needless connections (the code below has the Script initializing itself)). The View also has KnockOut bindings attached to it.

MVVM:

```
function AddressViewModel(rid, nick, line1, line2, city, state, zip)
{
    <!-- Modifiable Properties should be observable. This will allow Hub updates to flow to the View -->
    var self = this;
    self.rid = rid;
    self.nick = ko.observable(nick);
    self.line1 = ko.observable(line1);
    self.line2 = ko.observable(line2);
    self.city = ko.observable(city);
self.state = ko.observable(new StateViewModel(state.RID, state.Title, state.Abbreviation));
    self.zip = ko.observable(zip);
}
function StateViewModel(rid, title, abbreviation)
{
    <!-- States are a stagnant list. These will not be updated -->
    var self = this;
    self.rid = rid;
    self.title = title;
    self.abbreviation = abbreviation;
}
var Page = new function()
{

    //Page holds all Page's View Models. The init function can be modified to start only certain hubs.
    var page = this;
    page.init = function()
    {
        page.Account.init();
    }
    page.Account = new function ()
    {
            //Account holds account-specific information. Should only be retrieved on an encrypted, secure, and authorized connection. 
        account.init = function()
        {
            account.Addresses.init();
        }
        //Addresses manages the calls to Hubs and their callbacks to modify local content.
        account.Addresses = new function ()
        {
                    //Connect to the hub, and create an observable list.
            var addresses = this;
            addresses.hub = $.connection.accountAddressHub;
            addresses.list = ko.observableArray([]);

                    //Called on initial load. This calls the Index() function on the Hub.
            addresses.init = function ()
            {
                addresses.hub.server.index();
            }
                //displayMode allows for dynamic changing of the template.
            addresses.displayMode = ko.computed(function ()
            {
                return 'Address';
            });
                    //Empty allows to prompt user instead of just showing a blank screen.
            addresses.empty = ko.computed(function ()
            {
                if (addresses.list().length == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
                    //During initial load, unless if MVC provides the information with the View, the list will be empty until the first SignalR callback. This allows us to prompt the user we're still loading.
            addresses.loading = ko.observable(true);
                //The Hub's Index function ought to reach indexBack with a list of addresses. The addresses are then mapped to the list, using the local AddressViewModel. Sets initial load to false, as we now have addresses.
            addresses.hub.client.indexBack = function (addressList)
            {
                $.map(addressList, function (address)
                {
                    addresses.list.push(new AddressViewModel(address.RID, address.Nick, address.Line1, address.Line2, address.City, address.State, address.ZIP));
                });
                addresses.loading(false);
            }
         }
      }
}
```

On Run Script (Place in Layout, Script File, or View, depending on needs or confirgurations per page)

```
$(function ()
{
    //Configures what SignalR will do when starting, on receive, reconnected, reconnected, or disconnected. 
    $.connection.hub.starting(function ()
    {
        $('.updated').hide();
        $('.updating').show();
    });
    $.connection.hub.received(function ()
    {
        $('.updating').hide();
        $('.updated').show();
    });
    $.connection.hub.reconnecting(function ()
    {
        $('.updated').hide();
        $('.updating').show();
    });
    $.connection.hub.reconnected(function ()
    {
        $('.updating').hide();
        $('.updated').show();
    });
    //This will keep attempt to reconnect - the beauty of this, if the user unplugs the internet with page loaded, and then plugs in, the client reconnects automatically. However, the client would probably not receive any backlog - I haven't test that.
    $.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });
    //Apply knockout bindings, using the Page function from above.
    ko.applyBindings(Page);
    //Start the connection. 
    $.connection.hub.start(function ()
    {
    }).done(function ()
    {
            //If successfully connected, call the init functions, which propagate through the script to connect to all the necessary hubs.
        console.log('Connected to Server!');
        Page.init();
    })
    .fail(function ()
    {
        console.log('Could not Connect!');
    });;
});
```

LayOut:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        . . .
        @Styles.Render( "~/Content/css" )
        <!-- Load jQuery, KnockOut, and your MVVM scripts. -->
        @Scripts.Render( "~/bundles/jquery" )
        <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
        . . .
    </head>
    <body id="body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidenav">
        . . .
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="container">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </div>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial( "_Foot" ); }
    </body>
</html>
```

View (Index):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Account";
}
<div>
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial( "_AddressesWrapper" );
    }   
</div>
```

_AddressesWrapper:

```
<div data-bind="with: Page.Account.Addresses">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial( "_Address" );
    }
     <div id="Addresses" class="subcontainer">
         <div class="subheader">
            <div class="subtitle">
                <h2>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">
                    </span>
                        Addresses
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="AddressesContent" class="subcontent">
            <div class="row panel panel-primary">
                <!-- Check to see if content is empty. If empty, content may still be loading.-->
                <div data-bind="if: Page.Account.Addresses.empty">
                    <!-- Content is empty. Check if content is still initially loading -->
                    <div data-bind="if:Page.Account.Addresses.loading">
                        <!-- Content is still in the initial load. Tell Client. -->
                        <div class="well well-lg">
                            <p class="text-center">
                                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" width="50px" height="50px" />
                                <strong>We are updating your Addresses.</strong> This should only take a moment.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-bind="ifnot:Page.Account.Addresses.loading">
                        <!-- Else, if not loading, the Client has no addresses. Tell Client. -->
                        <div class="well well-lg">
                            <p class="text-center">
                                <strong>You have no Addresses.</strong> If you add an Addresses, you can view, edit, and delete it here.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Addresses is not empty -->
                <div data-bind="ifnot: Page.Account.Addresses.empty">
                    <!-- We have content to display. Bind the list with a template in the Partial View we loaded earlier -->
                    <div data-bind="template: { name: Page.Account.Addresses.displayMode, foreach: Page.Account.Addresses.list }">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

_Address:

```
<script type="text/html" id="Address">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 well well-sm">
        <address>
            <strong data-bind="text: nick"></strong><br>
            <span data-bind="text: line1"></span><br>
            <span data-bind="if: line2 == null">
                <span data-bind="text: line2"></span><br>
            </span>
            <span data-bind="text: city"></span>, <span data-bind=" text: state().abbreviation"></span> <span data-bind="text: zip"></span>
        </address>
    </div>
</script>
```

1. The KnockOut script interchanges with a SignalR Hub. The Hub receives the call, checks the authorization, if necessary, and passes the call to the proper repository or straight to WebAPI 2 (this example). The SignalR Hub action then takes the results of the API exchange and determines which function to call, and what data to pass.

   ```
   public class AccountAddressHub : AccountObjectHub
   {
       public override async Task Index()
       {
           //Connect to Internal API - Must be done within action.
           using( AddressController api = new AddressController(await this.Account()) )
           {
               //Make Call to API to Get Addresses:
               var addresses = api.Get();
               //Return the list only to Connecting ID.
               Clients.Client( Context.ConnectionId ).indexBack( addresses );
               //Or, return to a list of specific Connection Ids - can also return to all Clients, instead of adding a parameter.
               Clients.Clients( ( await this.ConnectionIds() ).ToList() ).postBack( Address );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. The API Controller checks data integrity and sends a callback to the same SignalR Hub action.

   ```
   public class AddressController 
       : AccountObjectController
   {
       ...
       // GET api/Address
       public ICollection<Address> Get()
       {
           //This returns back the calling Hub action.
           return Account.Addresses;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Your .NET application will need to use the same functions as your javascript-ran site. This will allow a modification from any client to then propagate to however many clients are needed (that single client who just loaded, as in this example, or to broadcast to everyone, or anywhere in between)

The end result is that the Hub receives changes/calls, calls the API, the API verifies the data and returns it back to the Hub. The Hub can then update all clients. You then successfully have real-time database changes and real-time client changes. The only catch is any change outside of this system will require the clients to refresh, which means all client calls, especially changes, **must** go through Hubs.

If you need more examples, I would be happy to show some. Obviously, security measures should be taken, and the code here is obviously only a small example.

Comment: will check it out later when I am free, as the required project has been finished, and now I have to spare some time for checking it out, I appreciate your help and concern, thank you very much dear

Answer (score 1):

If you want use signalr I think you should use [push server](http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html).But you can use another way and send a request to the api and the api should know about db change.

For push server you can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140164/signalr-console-app-example/12058856#12058856).

Comment: I am looking into the documentation now, will report back here after studying it

Answer (score 1):

There are some considerations that might help.

1- Since you are playing with the Access rights , so i would say that , you must check the access right at run time each time , user wants to access certain secured functionality , yes this will have some degradation in performance but ensure you the tighter granular security.

2- For sending periodic changes ,  i would say that , you can use Timer available in .Net and trigger changes at a certain interval.

3- I still don't like the idea of sending security related information to the client (thin) because anybody with basic knowledge of JavaScript and Html can change the security by running your site in debug mode or through some automated tools like Fiddler.

Comment: Your point number 3 has quite the irony mentioned, surely will discuss it with the managers

Comment: and BTW when I am trying to update the values of the variables stored in C# Classes, do I need to make use of javascript? I mean I am not altering anything on the UI

Answer (score 1):

I've made a library that proxies between a server side eventaggregator / service bus. It makes it alot easier to stream line the events being sent to clients. Take a look at the demo project here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Open the demo .sln and there is both a .NET client (WPF) and a javascript client example

Install using nuget

```
Install-Package SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
```

wiki

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: let me download and checkout your MVC demo project, plus the WiKi, will report back here after that

Comment: when I try to run your project demo it gives me an error **could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

Comment: That is strange, the project has .net 4.0 only dependencies so as long as you are usign VS2010 or newer you should be fine. are all nuget packages up to date etc?

Comment: yeah, NuGet restored the missing packages too